# Is the QUIC protocol secure?

Tags: encryption, tls, protocols

[QUIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC) is a new protocol for video streaming, that can establish a secure connection in one round. It is used in Google's new Duo app for example. How does it work and is it secure (comparison with TCP combined with TLS?).

Comment: How does it work: Techncial FAQ: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lmL9EF6qKrk7gbazY8bIdvq3Pno2Xj_l_YShP40GLQE/edit

Comment: Compared to TCP+TLS: Crypto doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g5nIXAIkN_Y-7XJW5K45IblHd_L2f5LTaDUDwvZ5L6g/edit

Comment: "The QUIC crypto protocol is *destined to die*. It will be replaced by TLS 1.3 in the future, but QUIC needed a crypto protocol before TLS 1.3 was even started."